# Is an avatar or talking head available in ROS?

Tags: ros, gazebo, visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am searching for an avatar like visualization in ROS.
So I have voice output and a face with speech animation that I can present on a tablet.

Right now, I only found gazebo and festival which could be usable.
Gazebo seems to me like a 3D editor similar to bender where I can load models through ROS and animate them. But I would just need something like a player that animates the face when there is voice output.

Has anyone a tip for me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12215/is-an-avatar-or-talking-head-available-in-ros?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [MORSE](http://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse/).

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am really not experienced with that but I would use Blender and its game engine.
You could create a 3D model of a face that would be animated on a simple input.

[This video](http://youtu.be/HcCM4vgZ8RI) is quite old and crappy but it shows a proof of concept of an arm being rendered in Blender and animated via a socket connection.
I think you could build something similar with a face in spite of an arm no?

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2011-12-11**:
Right now, it doesn't work from linux client to windows server. On a windows machine it works, but not ubuntu 10.04. The client does not connect to the windows server.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-12-06**:
Does xFace work? I see their last news is from 2008.

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2011-12-06**:
Thank you, it is kinda similar to gazebo. I also found xFace, that could also be a possibility. http://xface.fbk.eu/